# State-Space Model with categorical exogenous variables

Tags: state-space-models

I have a state-space model:
$$
x_{t+1} = A x_{t} + \alpha_{t} \\
y_{t+1} = B y_{t} + \beta_{t}
$$

The observation model is parameterized by a categorical exogenous variable, $$ a = M_1\  or \ M_2 $$
The observation equation:
$$
z_{t}(M_{1}) = x_t + y_t + \epsilon_t \\
z_t(M_2) = x_t - y_t + \epsilon_t
$$

Is this a valid space model where I can use a Kalman filter to generate state space estimators?